# Utilizar o history no angular js

Tags: angularjs

Existe alguma forma de utilizar o history do navegador em uma aplicação angular SPA?

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de busca de clientes e me foi solicitado que o usuário tenha a possibilidade de, por exemplo, quando forem feitas umas 5 buscas ter a possibilidade de ir voltando aos resultados das buscas feitas anteriormente.

Comment: Cara não sei se tem algo pronto pra isso, mas você pode usar um banco pra cache Redis, MongoDB, etc. E salvar as 5 ultimas consultas dos últimos usuários lá, depois vc pensa em como exibir esse histórico na tela e ao invés de buscar no seu banco normal vc busca no cache.

Comment: Uma possibilidade seria exibir na UI uma lista com as últimas consultas, e permitir que o usuário navegue entre elas.

Comment: Achei que tinha alguma biblioteca que fazia isso, vou ter mesmo que criar isso do zero. De qualquer forma obrigado DiegoAugusto e OnoSendai